# Is it incorrect to say number 3 is 'infront of' letter B in "B 3"? considering that front is a position a head of something

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, sentence

Is it incorrect to say number 3 is 'in front of' letter B in "B 3"? considering that front is a position ahead of something.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to say.  Normally European characters are read left to right, so B comes first.  That puts it in front of 3.  But, as Arkhem says, there are clearer ways to state this.

Answer (score 2):

Transposing dimensions to others is confusing in general as neither the B nor the 3 is in front or behind. One is to the left and one is to the right when talking about position. A clearer way could be to speak of the order of appearance. The B comes first and the 3 follows, which would be understood as we read from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the B is in front of 3 in "B3".

*B* is encountered first, so it is said to be in front of the *3*. It's quite normal and natural. You could also say *B* **precedes** *3*; again, something which precedes is in front.

The term is particularly used with currency symbols, where (say) the symbol £ is in front of the number.

This certainly fits the Lexico definition of "[in front of](https://www.lexico.com/definition/in_front_of)":

> In a position just ahead or at the front part of someone or something else.

OED hasn't been updated since 1898, but that has "the fore-part of anything, the part to which one normally comes first," which again is the *B* in B3. They have a number of new compound forms suggested, but nothing explicitly demonstrating "coming first when reading".